# When is an algebraic endomorphism a (Hamiltonian) symplectomorphism?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, symplectic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth, projective complex algebraic variety. Then the analytification of $X$ is a symplectic manifold, where the symplectic form is given by the restriction of Fubini-Study. Then every endomorphism of $X$ as a complex varity gives an endomorphism of $X$ as complex manifold. Not every algebraic morphism of $X$ is a symplectomorphism. My question is if there is some "algebraic" property ensureing that the induced morphism is a symplectomorphism? Similarly, is there an "algebraic" property telling us when an endomorphism induces a Hamiltonian symplectomorphism? My hope would be that if I take a finite order automorphism, that it might satisfy these properties. Apologies for the stupid question.

Comment: I doubt there is an algebraic condition. An equivalent geometric condition (which is frequently useful) is that the automorphism is an isometry of $X$. One reason it's useful is that the isometry group of a compact Riemannian manifold is again compact. Also, it allows you to use Riemannian Geometry tools (and these are quite different from the Symplectic Geometry tools) to analyze such automorphisms.